# How do I exclude return traffic from my ACL?

Tags: cisco, access-control-list

I have [this network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc7sR.png). What I try to achieve is: Deny access from `Network 172.28.224.0` to `Network 172.28.226.208`. But the other way around it should work. `172.28.226.208` should be allowed to access `172.28.224.0`

I have tried it with the following ACL on the Router

```
access-list 101 permit ospf any any
access-list 101 permit icmp any any
access-list 101 deny ip any 172.28.226.208 0.0.0.7
access-list 101 permit ip any any

int f0/0.1
access-group 101 out
```

I am using ospf and my problem is, that when I return traffic is also blocked by the ACL. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This question is perhaps better asked at the Network Engineering Stack Exchange: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You state you want to deny traffic from 172.28.224.0 to 172.28.226.208 (which subnet masks?) yet you deny traffic from ANY to 172.28.226.208/29.

Next you apply the ACL in the outbound direction on Fa0/0.1 but the destination (172.28.226.208/29) does not live there so you should apply the ACL inbound instead.

Apply the ACL inbound instead of outbound and fix the "ANY" statement and it should work.